# NSInternalInconsistencyException while deleting cell from collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I want to delete a cell from a UICollectionView. While deleting cell I get

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).' Error.

Here is my code:

```
[self.imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexForDelete];

[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexForDelete inSection:0];
     [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

 }];
```

I am appending one dummy cell when my array count is not 5
Here is code for numberOfItems in numberOfItemsInSection

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.imgArray.count == 5)
    {
        return  self.imgArray.count ;
    }
    else
    {
        return  self.imgArray.count + 1;
    }

}
```

I found many solution on Google and Stackoverflow but nothing found help full for me.

Comment: You don't need the `performBatchUpdates` for a single delete.  get rid of that and just keep the two lines that are inside the block.

Comment: Can you show your `numberOfItemsInSection` method?

Comment: see my updated question. @Paulw11

Comment: So that code explains your problem.  You have 5 items in the array, so `numberOfItemsInSection` returns 5, then you delete 1, so now you have 4, but `numberOfItemsInSection` still returns 5.  This is exactly what your exception says.  Why do you have that if statement?

Comment: @Paulw11 : you are right. Exactly 5 will raise issue.

Comment: i want to show maximum 5 items in collection view. if there is 5 objects in array then no need to extra one item of add (+) to the collection view thats why i have used code in numberOfItemsInSection.

Answer (score 0):

**performBatchUpdates** mainly used to perform actions for multiple cells. i.e. delete, insert, move.

Try this,

```
[self.collectionObj performBatchUpdates:^{

    [self.imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexForDelete];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexForDelete inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

You can also try directly for 1 cell delete without using **performBatchUpdates**

```
    [self.imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexForDelete];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexForDelete inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Hope, this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: While this will fix the issue, I would suggest that you add some commentary explaining why updating the array inside the `performBatchUpdates` is necessary

Comment: @sohanvanani How did you manage 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' method ?

Comment: if([indexPath row] == self.imgArray.count)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add_Gallary"];
    }
    else
    {
           //cell item from imgArray;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to separate the update into two stages to avoid the NSInternalInconsistencyException.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isMyCollectionViewUpdating;

//...

[self.imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexForDelete];

[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

     self.isMyCollectionViewUpdating = YES; 

     NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexForDelete inSection:0];
     [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.isMyCollectionViewUpdating = NO;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

and for the collection view numberOfItemInSection

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (self.isMyCollectionViewUpdating)
        {
            return self.imgArray.count;
        } else {
            if(self.imgArray.count == 5)
            {
                return  self.imgArray.count ;
            }
            else
            {
                return  self.imgArray.count + 1;
            }
        }


    }
```